# WordPress custom permalink and archive link for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have custom post type `venue` and custom taxonomy 'facility' and 'types',
is it possible to generate custom permalinks for the single post and archive with current posts taxonomy slug. 
Example:

---

single post term `facility` slug is 'restaurant'

http://mywebsite.com/restaurant/restaurant-name

---

---

archive page

http://mywebsite.com/restaurants

---

My custom post declaration

```
$args = array(
  'label'                 => __( 'Venue', 'weera' ),
  'description'           => __( 'Dubai day Venue listings', 'weera' ),
  'labels'                => $labels,
  'supports'              => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
  'hierarchical'          => false,
  'public'                => true,
  'show_ui'               => true,
  'show_in_menu'          => true,
  'menu_position'         => 5,
  'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-palmtree',
  'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
  'can_export'            => true,
  'has_archive'           => true,
  'exclude_from_search'   => false,
  'publicly_queryable'    => true,
  'capability_type'       => 'page',
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'restaurant'),
  'has_archive' => true,
);
register_post_type( 'venue', $args );
```

My taxonomy 'facility' declaration

```
$args = array(
  'labels'                     => $labels,
  'hierarchical'               => true,
  'public'                     => true,
  'show_ui'                    => true,
  'show_admin_column'          => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
  'show_tagcloud'              => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'venue' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'facility', array( 'venue' ), $args );
```

but http://mywebsite.com/restaurants and http://mywebsite.com/restaurant/restaurant-name both gives 404 pages.

Comment: did you save permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either go into `Settings -> Permalinks` and click Save

Or if you're doing this programmatically you need to use `flush_rewrite_rules()`, but make sure this is only used when you activate/deactivate the plugin, DON'T set this in code that runs (like in init, or on every page load):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wdocs_flush_rewrites' );


/**
 * Flush rewrite rules on activation
 */
function wpdocs_flush_rewrites() {
    // call your CPT registration function here (it should also be hooked into 'init')
    wpdocs_custom_post_types_registration();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```